# Invoking validation just after display the form JSF

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a form where the user should be able to save even if there are validation errors.
These errors should be displayed once the user get into the form again.
So, i would like to invoke the validation of the entire form just after the form is displayed.

Currently, the validation is handled thru AJAX with several custom validators by using `<f:validator/>` and `<p:ajax/>` only when the user edits the field

Any suggestion is welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to submit the form after it loads directly.

To achieve this you can use `p:remoteCommand`  and something like `jQuery('document').ready(function(){remoteCommandName()})`

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering. The problem would be that when there are no errors, the form will be sent and the user won't be able to edit the form.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by the user won't be able to edit the form ?